# How do I resolve the DataCloneError when using web3 and react

Tags: web3js

I'm trying to add a small amount of web3 code to a react component. When I do so, I'm getting a DataCloneError. The component is as follows:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Web3 from 'web3';

class App extends Component {
  async componentDidMount() {
    const web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
    await window.ethereum.enable()
    web3.eth.getAccounts().then(console.log)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Hello Web3
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

The error I'm getting is

```
inpage.js:1 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Window': function (error, response) {
            if (!error) {
              resolve(response);
            }

        ...<omitted>... } could not be cloned.
    at i._write (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/inpage.js:1:114976)
    at b (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/inpage.js:1:133822)
    at w (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/inpage.js:1:134428)
    at i.g.uncork (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/inpage.js:1:137191)
    at i._onMessage (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/inpage.js:1:114856)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have a similar issue with web3 1.0.0 beta46 and beta47. It works with beta33.
Which version are you using?

Comment: I was using beta47. reverting to beta33 ressolved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reverting to web3@1.0.0-beta.33 resolved the issue.